# Prove that if a functional is in the dual space then the null space of the functional is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis

$X$ is a normed vector space and $T \in X^*$. Show that 
\begin{equation} \label{prob}
    T \in X' \Leftrightarrow N(T) \; \text{is closed},
\end{equation}
where $N(f)$ is the null space of $T$.

i) Prove that if $T \in X'$, then $N(T)$ is closed.

ii) Assume that $T$ is unbounded. Show that then $N(T)$ is not closed.

iii) Make an argument that (i) and (ii) together prove \eqref{prob}.

---

My current suggestions.

i) Let $\{v_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in N(T)$ such that $v_n \rightarrow v$. Because $v_n \in N(T)$ then $Tv_n = 0$. Now $T \in X'$ is bounded and linear giving $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Tv_n = Tv$ giving us $Tx = 0$. Therefore we must have $v \in N(T)$. Thus $N(T)$ is closed (I got this conclusion from a theorem in a book by Kreyszig).

ii) I'm not sure here, but my idea is to take a sequence $v_n \in X$ converging to $v$ and a sequence $y_n \in N(T)$, and then prove that $y \rightarrow v$ thus proving that $N(T)$ is not closed. I don't know exactly how this should be done.

iii) This I don't know but since I haven't used that $T \in X^*$ I have a feeling that I should use this?

---

To clarify: $X^*$ is the normed space of all linear functionals and $X'$ is the normed space of all linear and bounded functionals.

Comment: To clarify, is $X^*$ the space of all linear maps $X \to \mathbb{C}$ (or whatever the base field is), and $X'$ the subspace of bounded/continuous ones?

Comment: I see how that could be unclear. I will clarify in the post. Thanks

Comment: Isn't it enough to say that $\{0\}$ is closed and $T$ is continuous so $T^{-1}(\{0\}) = \ker T$ is closed? For part i), that is.

Comment: @Andrew Sure it is. The proof used in the question is basically the proof of the equivalence between the two notions of continuity ("topological" and sequential) for metric spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove (ii) by contradiction: Suppose $N(T)$ is closed, then $Y:= X/N(T)$ is a normed linear space, and the quotient map
$$
\pi : X\to Y
$$
is a bounded linear map. Now, by the first isomorphism theorem, $T$ induces an injective map
$$
\overline{T} : Y\to \mathbb{C}
$$
Furthermore, $Y$ is finite dimensional (in fact, one dimensional) because if $y_0 \notin N(T)$, then it is an easy check that
$$
Y = \text{span}(y_0 + N(T))
$$
Since any two norms on $Y$ are equivalent, it follows that $\overline{T}$ is also continuous. Hence,
$$
T = \overline{T}\circ \pi
$$
must also be continuous. This contradiction proves (ii).